# What could interfere with changing iframe contents with href?

Tags: links, formatting, genesis-theme-framework

On one v4.1 Wordpress site the following code works as expected:

```
<a href="http://astore.amazon.com/l0c39-20?_encoding=UTF8&node=6" target="test">Test link</a>
<iframe src="http://astore.amazon.com/l0c39-20" height="1000" name="test" id="test"></iframe>
```

On another, which in contrast to the first site is running Genesis (though I can't tell if that's relevant), clicking the `Test link` opens the source in a new window, not in the iframe.  How can I determine what's breaking the reference to the iframe, or the hyperlink functionality, on the second site?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23816486/2662901 suggests that the iframe "src" property might be helpful here, but I don't know enough to figure out how....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ha: by searching the rendered page for `target` I discovered that the site was running a plugin called "Open external links in a new window."  Disabling that plugin solved the problem.